# Stripe iOS SDK and NodeJS API: Is there a way to create a Source from a Payment Method?

Tags: ios, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe's STPPaymentContext payment options view controller as stated per Stripe's basic iOS integration guide: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic. This results in a Payment Method for the customer as intended.

However, I'm working with legacy code that uses Sources and Charges instead of Payment Methods and Payment Intents. The workflow of the app was designed around default sources for a customer so Payment Methods don't really work here unless I go with subscriptions or invoices, which I'll do as a last resort but hoping to avoid.

Is there a way to create a Source from the resulting Payment Method from the first step? I can then manually attach this Source to the customer and set it as the default.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, you cannot get a Source or Token from `STPPaymentContext`.  That API no longer uses the legacy Stripe objects.  You can [read more about this change in the Stripe iOS SDK changelog](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1600-2019-07-18).

The only way to use `STPPaymentContext` with Sources is to downgrade the Stripe iOS SDK to a version prior to 16.x, which is not recommended.

If possible you should update your legacy code that uses Sources and Charges to use Payment Methods and Payment Intents.  Stripe provides [a migration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/transitioning) to help you with this.

Comment: Yes I've since decided to upgrade the app and go with Payment Methods and Payment Intents. It will require some refactoring but it can't be helped.